# what keys are returned by ssh-keyscan

Tags: ssh

I understand that one of prerequisite for correct login using keys it is needed to add the server's key to client's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` There is also utility called `ssh-keyscan` which return keys of specific host. Those keys then could be added to client's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` event if `StrictHostKeyChecking yes` is used in client's `~/.ssh/config` for particular host, so client can then connect to server, e.g.:

```
Host 192.168.1.100
    StrictHostKeyChecking yes
    user wakatana
```

My question is, which keys are returned by following command? From where are they read? Are they stored on server, where?

`ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.100 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

I've compared all `*.pub` keys from `/etc/ssh` with output of `ssh-keyscan` but nothing matched.

PS: this is for my better SSH understanding

Answer (score 1):

1. `ssh-keyscan` returns the fingerprint of a key, not the actual pub key. When you make a SSH session, two different key pairs (with a fingerprint for each pair) are involved.
2. The keys a SSH server uses to identify itself when you login to it are located in `/etc/ssh/` and usually named something like `ssh_host_rsa_key`.
   You can actually change where the SSH server looks for the key in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with the `HostKey /path/to/host/key` setting.